# Two installations of texlive

Tags: texlive, auctex, linux

I installed TeXLive 2014 complete from a DVD on Fedora 21. I have set the PATH as per the instructions to `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux` and it is working correctly.

While installing `auctex` for Emacs via yum, it created another install of texlive in `/usr/share/`. Now the problem is  that when I run udpmap-sys to update the fonts it writes to the `/usr/share/texlive/` instead of the `/usr/local/texlive` directory. Same is true with `mktexlsr`.

So result of this is that I cannot use the new fonts that I have installed, as they are updated in the `/usr/share/` folder instead of the `/usr/local` where the main TL2014 install is.

Is there a way to resolve this? So that `updmap-sys` and `mktexlsr` write the files to the `/usr/local/` instead of `/usr/share` directory?

Comment: i put the path to the tex binaries at the start of the global search path list.  in fact, i go so far as to have an alias to a command that does that, i my login script; of course it _has_ to be a shell command — mine is actually `export PATH=/local/cache/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`

Comment: A second option, untested since I have no Fedora systems: [texlive dummy package](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8782/texlive-dummy-package/).